# 'mutex': is not a member of 'std', error when using Armadillo in CLR

Tags: c++-cli, clr, armadillo

I am using Armadillo in c++ CLR, when I include armadillo in my solution and building it, I get this error:

```
missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
'mutex': is not a member of 'std'
'cache-mutex':unknown override specifier
```

Here is my code and I have not written anything yet:

```
#include "pch.h"

#include <include/armadillo>

using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{


}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please provide [mre]. For instance: did you include the correct header?

Comment: The message refers to something in the headers, probably from inside Armadillo. `std::mutex` is incompatible with CLR.

Answer (score 1):

Define a macro named `ARMA_DONT_USE_STD_MUTEX` before `#include`ing the armadillo header. Example:

```
#define ARMA_DONT_USE_STD_MUTEX
#include <armadillo>
```

The [documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#config_hpp) says:

> `ARMA_DONT_USE_STD_MUTEX`
> Disable use of std::mutex; applicable if your compiler and/or environment doesn't support std::mutex